# Tailwind-css: Text not aligning next to an image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I just started to learn tailwind-css and implementing it in a new ReactJS project. I have a Navbar, with a Logo and a text (Budget 123) at the left.. and a sign out button at the right. No matter what I do, the text next to the logo is always aligning to the top of the Navbar. I want it to be aligned in the middle.

Below is my code related to the logo and the text

```
<div className=" w-full shadow-xl bg-white">
      <nav>
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center h-full w-full px-4 2xl:px-16 ">
          <div className="inline-flex ">
            <a href="/">
              <img
                src="{logo}"
                alt="logo"
                width="80"
                className="cursor-pointer p-2"
              ></img>
            </a>
            <span className=" font-bold md:text-2xl xs:text-lg text-orange-600 text-center">
              **Budget 123**
            </span>
          </div>
....
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

I tried many scenarios as per tailwind-css documentation. But the set always stay top aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the classes `flex items-center` to the span to vertically center the text which should then line up with the logo.

```
<span className="flex items-center font-bold md:text-2xl xs:text-lg text-orange-600 text-center">
    **Budget 123**
</span>
```